# Why anova disappear in robust regression

Tags: regression, anova, r-squared, robust

My question is this: When we run OLS regression, an ANOVA table is given but when we run robust regression, then the ANOVA table and adjusted $R^2$ values are not shown. Why?

I want to know the logic behind it, and by ANOVA I mean analysis of variance.

Comment: Can you show examples to clarify your question?

Comment: What do you mean by "ANOVA is disappear"?  (This seems like a language problem, if you can find someone who can help translate what you mean, that would help).

Also, of course the SE change when you do robust regression -- that's sort of the point. When you do robust regression you are adjusting the model to deal with outliers and influential points; one way to do this is to adjust the SE.

Comment: By ANOVA I mean analysis of variance in ols regression

Comment: I want to ask when we run ols regression it gives us anova table and when we run robust regression anova table disappear from the results and standard errors are also change why?

Comment: I want to know the logic behind it

Answer (score 1):

Because ANOVA is equivalent to linear regression, so it is straightforward to give an ANOVA table for that. But there is no such equivalent for robust regression, so, no such table is printed.

The standard errors change because you are assuming different things. In particular, you are making fewer assumptions about the residuals in robust regression than in OLS; the exact nature of the changes depends on the type of robust regression you do.